# How to stop showing loading if recyclerView is shown?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to stop showing progressbar if recycler is shown

```
 ProgressBar progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
    if (recyclerView.isShown()){
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

This is my xml in android studio

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressbar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

 <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/all_user_post_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/search_posts" />
```

i want adapter to be in mainactivity and adapter will display in mainactivity okay and that's it i guess

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText search;
String currentUserID;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private List<Posts> postList;
private AdapterPost adapterPost;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    MultiDex.install(this);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.all_user_post_list);

    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new 
    LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
    layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    postList = new ArrayList<>();

    LoadEveryUsersPosts();
```

Comment: Could you provide more details? Your progress bar `setVisibility` seems to be correct. It might be your recyclerview

Comment: what details you want? thanks for your time

Comment: Are you trying to check if recyclerview is shown? If yes, try my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
    View recyclerview= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.all_user_post_list);
    recyclerview.getViewTreeObserver()
                    .addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onGlobalLayout() {
                              progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                              recyclerview.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                        //prevent infinite loop
                                }
                            });
```

Comment: Here is the docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener

Comment: I get error: View.getViewTreeObserver()' on a null object reference thanks for your time

Comment: @Hio I am not sure why it doesn't show but did you check if your progressbar is visible? Try removing progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE); for now and check

Comment: @Hio does it show the progress bar when you removed it?

Comment: i have adapter and i want adapter to in mainactivity

Comment: @Hio You want the adapter to be displayed in mainactivity? You can set it there. Then put the above code after setting the adapter. I am not sure why your progress bar doesn't show since it is supposed to do so. Please give more details and show me your code.

Comment: hey, i added as you said

Comment: @Hio Your adapter isn't there. Check this docs: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview#java    You can switch to Java code by clicking it

Comment: Thanks bro :)  for your help. I am so happy that you help me and I think you are happy too. yeah I solved my problem it's because of you.  You have a good day or night whatever. :)

Comment: @Hio Thanks. If this helped you please upvote my answer and mark it as correct so I can get reputation points as well. Good Luck in your project!

Comment: @Hio I would also suggest you to start learning Kotlin. It is better than Java now since Android devs are updating it. Code is easier there then everything else is more efficient